# Ansible loop over inventory file (two dimensional list)

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I would like to parse a two dimensional list from the inventory file with ansible playbook

Inventory file: `.ini` would have a list of macs and IPs

> ```
> mac1=b8:27:eb:12:53:1b ip1=192.168.8.101
> mac2=b8:27:eb:f1:65:32 ip2=192.168.8.102
> ...
> ```

and the ansible task would be to add a line everytime in the `/etc/ethers``file in this form

> b8:27:eb:f1:65:32 192.168.8.102

this is the task

```
- name: Assign static IPs to MACs
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ethers
    line: "{{  mac  }} {{  ip  }}"
    mode: 0644
  loop: "{{ listname }}"
  become: yes
```

Any recommendations please on how to set my list in the inventory that it will work with the playbook?
Thank you!

Comment: Your example ini file is not an ansible inventory file. Do your really need to define that info in your inventory attached to a specific host ? If not, do your really need to have that info in an ini file ?

Comment: yes @Zeitounator, What I meant there, is thats the info that I want to include in the ini file, but I dint know exactly how to put them?
how to add a list called listname, that has a list of two fields (Macs and IPs) for every member

Comment: Is that ini file on your controller or on the target host ? And from your last comment, sorry but I do not get if you can change the format of that file or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the list as a variable in group_var folder or in your playbook.

```
list:
  - mac: b8:27:eb:12:53:1b
    ip: 192.168.8.101
  - mac: b8:27:eb:f1:65:32
    ip: 192.168.8.102
```

Your task can then look something like this:

```
- name: Assign static IPs to MACs
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/ethers
    line: "{{  item.mac  }} {{  item.ip  }}"
    mode: 0644
  loop: "{{ list }}"
  become: yes
```